# Android log my application tags to file

Tags: android, logging

I have googled a lot but haven't came up with anything usefull.

I would like to log everything from my application to the file!

My first thought was something like this:

```
try {
        File filename = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logfile.log"); 
        filename.createNewFile(); 
        String cmd = "logcat -d -f com.packagename:D *:S "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the problem is that it would log everything with tag name `com.packagename`! Is there any way how to log everything regarding only my application? Errors etc to file? 
Maybe there are some frameworks which I could use?

Comment: why can't you use `logcat com.packagename.yourapp`?

Comment: Wouldn't i log everything? Because running `adb logcat com.yourpackage.name` in console it logs everything even the stuff which aren't connected to my app

Answer (score 0):

I have used [logback](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) in couple of Android applications. It provides all the features of original loggers like SLF4J.

You can have a look and ask for help if you need any help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, will read the documentation and if I will have any questions will ask!